# Nexus : proxy and virtualize maven1 repositories

Tags: repository, virtual, nexus

I installed nexus 1.9.2.3 and I'm trying to proxy a maven 1 repository:
http://maven.restlet.org/

To do so, I created the maven1 proxy and then, created a virtual repository (M1->M2).

My server settings seems to be ok since I'm able to browse the repo in the "Browse Remote" tab, but I'm not able to find artifacts using the "Artifact Search" or with maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.restlet</groupId>
<artifactId>org.restlet.ext.wadl</artifactId>
<version>1.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Others maven2 artifacts are retrieved successfully and I don't understand why m1 artifacts are not found. How should I fetch artifacts from a maven1 proxied repository?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This wont work because the repository URL you are mentioning is a Maven 2 repository and NOT a Maven 1 repository. So you have to configure it as a Maven 2 repo and turn virtual repository from m2 to m1.